# Simplifying shorthand if bool

Tags: c#, .net

I just declared a variable like this:

```
bool b = (x is Foo) ? (x as Foo).Bar == 1 ? false;
```

But resharper told me that I could simplify the expression, so I rewrote it like this:

```
bool b = (x as Foo).Bar == 1;
```

Amd now resharper is satisfied, but is "exception safe"? For example, will it return false if `x` isnt of the type `Foo`?

Comment: you can also write `bool b =(x is Foo) && ((x as Foo).Bar == 1)` - slightly shorter

Comment: Maybe the reason for the recommendation was due to the fact that the second `?` needs to be `:`   - `bool b = (x is Foo) ? (x as Foo).Bar == 1 : false;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second will throw a `NullReferenceException` if x isn't of the type `Foo`

Comment: `(x as Foo)` will return `null` if the cast is not possible, then when you try to access `Bar` property it will throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

I think Resharper is complaining, because the first version casts twice. This will only cast once:

```
Foo xAsFoo = x as Foo;
bool b = (xAsFoo != null) ? xAsFoo.Bar == 1 : false;
```

Or shorter:

```
Foo xAsFoo = x as Foo;
bool b = (xAsFoo != null) && xAsFoo.Bar == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why *Resharper* tell this, but it wrong.

As in the case, when `x` is **not** Foo, it will raise an exception.

```
bool b = (x as Foo).Bar == 1; //IF X IS SOMETHING ELSE, EXCEPTION !
```

as the as operator allow to **run** cast, but in case of the failure, returns `null`. 
So `x as Foo == null`, and accessing property of `null` will raise an exception.